# Argument of type int[8][8] gets turned into int(*)[8]

Tags: c++, arrays, types

```
using T=int[8][8];    //1
                      //2
T a={0};              //3
void f(T b){          //4
     a=b;             //5 
}                     //6
```

Even though a and b should both be of type T when the function f is called,
my compiler says there's an error in line 5: "incompatible types in assignment of 'int(*)[8]' to 'T' {aka 'int [8][8]'}".
Why is b not of type T like I declared in line 4?

Comment: You can't assign one array to another. You need to copy.

Comment: That's standard. Declaring an argument as an array will always have it treated as a pointer, because of array to pointer *decay*.

Comment: But the main problem isn't the decay, but rather that you attempt to assign to an array, which is invalid (as mentioned). If you need to assign to an array, either use `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ (and C) you cannot pass an array by value to a function. If you declare a function with an array as it's argument, the type of the argument is "adjusted" to be a pointer. For that reason, your argument is a pointer. You can pass it by reference:

```
void f(T const& b);
```

That would be an array reference, but you can't really use `=` to assign an array. You could use a loop, [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy), or [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to do that. Or, you can use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for friendly value semantics:

```
using T = std::array<std::array<int, 8>, 8>;
                      
T a; 
void f(T const& b) { // could also pass by value
     a = b; // assignment is OK
}
```